# Conditional statement not checking the actual condition in a list

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I've written a code to take certain strings as an input and formed a list with those inputs and then use conditional statement on the list but the list seems to be bypassing the condition no matter what the input is.

I would love it someone could tell me what mistake I am doing here.

```
while done == 'n':
    if data == 'y':
        # Input for databases
        data_n = input('How many databases would you like to download? (Max 4 as of now): ')

        n = int(data_n)
        i = 0
        name = ['a']*n

        print('Available databases as of now: \n Baltic wave analysis and forecasts (bw) \n Global wave analysis and '
              'forecasts (gw) \n Baltic sea physics analysis and forecast (bp) \n Global ocean 1/12\u00b0 physics '
              'analysis and forecast (gp)')

        for i in range(0, n):
            name[i] = input('Enter the name of the database you would like to download: ')

        # Input for the location data
        while done == 'n':
            if 'bw' or 'bp' in name:
                print('Max range for longitudes in Baltic sea: 9\u00b0 to 30\u00b0')
                print('Max range for latitudes in Baltic sea: 53\u00b0 to 66\u00b0')
                longitude_min_b = input('Enter west limit: ')
                longitude_max_b = input('Enter east limit: ')
                latitude_min_b = input('Enter south limit: ')
                latitude_max_b = input('Enter north limit: ')
            elif 'gw' or 'gp' in name:
                print('Max range for global longitudes: -180\u00b0 to 180\u00b0')
                print('Max range for global latitudes: -80\u00b0 to 90\u00b0')
                longitude_min_g = input('Enter west limit: ')
                longitude_max_g = input('Enter east limit: ')
                latitude_min_g = input('Enter south limit: ')
                latitude_max_g = input('Enter north limit: ')
            else:
                print('Not a valid input.')
            done = input('Done? (Y/N): ').lower()
```

This is what happens when I run the code and enter some arbitrary string values.

```
How many databases would you like to download? (Max 4 as of now): 2
Available databases as of now: 
 Baltic wave analysis and forecasts (bw) 
 Global wave analysis and forecasts (gw) 
 Baltic sea physics analysis and forecast (bp) 
 Global ocean 1/12° physics analysis and forecast (gp)
Enter the name of the database you would like to download: a
Enter the name of the database you would like to download: c
Max range for longitudes in Baltic sea: 9° to 30°
Max range for latitudes in Baltic sea: 53° to 66°
Enter west limit:
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: haven't tested this in python myself, but I think the issue is that you need ('bw' in name) or ('bp' in name)

Equivalent checks using `any` would work as well, but the problem is that a non-empty string evaluates to `True`

Comment: @Shffl It works. Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to change your if condition to

```
if 'bw' in name or 'bp' in name:
      #code
elif 'gw' in name or 'gp' in name:
      #code
```

Comment: That works. Thank you so much.